# MSBuild task failing - Not running in Single Thread Apartment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a custom MsBuild task that sends an email (does some special stuff while sending the email -like formatting content).

**Background**:

Using TFS 2008

Build server is a separate machine using TeamBuild 2008.

This custom task used to work fine until I installed .Net 4.0 on the build machine and setup the build service to use the new version of MSBuild (Configured Team Build 2008 to use MSBuild 4.0 instead of MSBuild 3.5 by setting the **MSBuildPath** property to c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006)

**The error that I get is:**

```
"...\TFSBuild.proj" (EndToEndIteration target) (1) -> (EmailResults target) -> ...\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(386,5): error : SendEmailTask failed: ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
```

The `SendEmailTask` uses `SmtpClient` to send an email. (my suspicion is that the `SmtpClient` is using some underlying ActiveX object which is throwing this error).

How do I get MsBuild to invoke the custom task in a STA environment?

Comment: I found that the custom task was using an instance of a WebBrowser class to do some work!, which is what was causing the "Not running in Single Thread Apartment". Once the WebBrowser class was removed, the error went away. (More info on WebBrowser and the fact that it can only run in a STA thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build task is trying to start Internet Explorer.  Yes, it needs an STA thread, and no, you can't get one out of MSBuild.exe

How you got from SmtpClient to Internet Explorer is completely unclear to me.  Using an HTML body or some kind an attachment sounds all pretty remote to me.  Having your build task start a program that does the job instead at least ought to give you a better diagnostic.

Comment: Hans, how did you determine that the task is using IE? And I suspect you are right. The code is trying to email body that contains HTML and that is probably why its trying to load IE (not sure though). But why did this work under MsBuild 3.5 and not MsBuild 4.0

Comment: From the Guid in the error message.  I can't really guess what changed in MSBuild 4.  Try connect.microsoft.com